# Returning 0 or NULL on MySQL Interval query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return a data set of row counts for the last 7 days, currently my result looks like this;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count(*)] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count(*)] => 2
        )

)
```

However I require that the days where the result was 0, that is displays 0 so i have 7 results in order.

This is my query so far;

```
"SELECT count(*) 
   FROM tbl_users 
  WHERE date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= created 
     AND NOW() >= created 
  GROUP BY date(created)"
```

The only other option would be to have "count(*) as date", with date being the actual date of the count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To do what you want you should have a table with all days and left join with your interval and use a SUM instead COUNT. The count only bring results for those that exists in your table. say that your interval is from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-10 and you have theese registries: 2013-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 2013-01-03 it will result in: 2, 1, 1 there is no way for the sql to know that should exist 01-04, 01-05, 01-06... 01-10

Comment: If you could provide a working example it would be excellent! I'm totally confused on this one :(

Answer (score 1):

As I said on the comments: you should have a table with all days and left join with your interval and use a SUM instead COUNT. The count only bring results for those that exists in your table. Say that your interval is from `2013-01-01 to 2013-01-10` and you have theese registries:

```
Created
2013-01-01, 
2013-01-01, 
2013-01-02, 
2013-01-03
```

it will result in: `2, 1, 1`

there is no way for the sql to know that should exist `01-04, 01-05, 01-06... 01-10`

So you have to create the data of the days and left join with your table. Something like this:

Some data example:

```
create table tbl_users(
    created date
);

insert into tbl_users values
    ( '2013-11-24' ), 
    ( '2013-11-24' ),
    ( '2013-11-25' ),
    ( '2013-11-25' ),
    ( '2013-11-25' ),
    ( '2013-11-26' ),
    ( '2013-11-27' ),
    ( '2013-11-27' ),
    ( '2013-11-27' ),
    ( '2013-11-28' ),
    ( '2013-11-29' );


create table alldays (
    dateday date
);

--this is just an example to fit the result for today: 2013-11-28
--this table should have all days for the year
insert into alldays values
     ( '2013-11-23' ),
     ( '2013-11-24' ),
     ( '2013-11-25' ),
     ( '2013-11-26' ),
     ( '2013-11-27' ),
     ( '2013-11-28' ),
     ( '2013-11-29' ),
     ( '2013-11-30' ),
     ( '2013-12-01' ),
     ( '2013-12-02' ),
     ( '2013-12-03' );
```

Your query should be:

```
 SELECT a.dateday, sum( if(b.created is null, 0, 1) ) 
   FROM alldays a left join tbl_users b on (a.dateday=b.created)
  WHERE a.dateday >= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  
    AND a.dateday <= NOW()
  GROUP BY a.dateday
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cee122/7

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySql CASE statement, as indicated here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html

Ex:

```
   CASE YOUR QUERY
   WHEN IS NULL THEN 0
   [ELSE statement_list]
  END CASE
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im confused how It would go into my query, could you help?